# Change the font color into white - JS

Tags: javascript

What code should I insert within this line of code to change the font color into white and how should I do it ?

```
document.getElementById('clockbox').innerHTML=""+tday[nday]+", "+tmonth[nmonth]+" "+ndate+", "+nyear+" | "+nhour+":"+nmin+":"+nsec+ap+"";
setTimeout("GetClock()", 1000);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var x = document.getElementById('clockbox');
x.style.color = '#FFFFFF';
```

Answer (score 0):

Just:

```
document.getElementById('clockbox').style.color="white";
```